# React Can't pass ID parameter of <input/> to event handler by e.target.id

Tags: reactjs, events, input, react-state-management

This is a basic practice of state management in React [react.dev](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-duplication-in-state), the code should work like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/manage-statement-avoid-duplication-in-state-kqq89y):

And this is my code : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/managing-state-02-4-avoid-duplication-in-state-when-it-coms-to-editable-why-this-wont-work-forked-yjp6j4?file=/src/App.js)

I tried to pass the `id`of the active `<input/>` as `e.target.id` to `handleChange()`, but failed,

I know I can pass the `id` parameter like this :
`<input value={item.title} onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e, item.id)} />`

But I'm curious to know why it fails when it comes to `e.target.id` ?

Thanks a lot.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const initialItems = [
  { title: "pretzels", id: 0 },
  { title: "crispy seaweed", id: 1 },
  { title: "granola bar", id: 2 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);
  
  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id); // i got the id number correctly
    const result = items.filter((item)=>item.id===e.target.id) 
    console.log(result)// I got a empty array 

    setItems(
      items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === e.target.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            title: e.target.value
          };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  const collection = items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <input value={item.title} id={item.id} onChange={handleChange} />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>What's your travel snack?</h1>
      <ul>{collection}</ul>
      <p>You picked </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `e.target.id` is a _string_, and `"1" !== 1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe GOSH you're right !!!